# window function clarification in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is probably simple. I am implementing the charts plugin from http://www.chartjs.org/

In the bar.html sample file it has this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bar Chart</title>
        <script src="../Chart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 50%">
            <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
        </div>


    <script>
    var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};

    var barChartData = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
        datasets : [
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
            },
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
            }
        ]

    }
    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
            responsive : true
        });
    }

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the code it has window.myBar= new Chart....

What is myBar?  Is this just a variable like any other variable? What does the window. in front of it do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
    responsive : true
});
```

**`window.myBar`**

This is a reference to a [global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) variable that the code immediately after creates. Later this can be referenced alone by `myBar`. Global variables should be avoided in JavaScript code.

**`= new Chart(ctx)`**

Calls the `Chart()` function in the [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#The_Constructor) syntax, passing to the drawing context for the `<canvas>`.

**`.Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });`**

Calls `Bar()`, a method of `Chart`s , passing the `barChartData` and a literal object `{ responsive: true }`. Used like this, the [literal object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Creating_objects) is a set of options that `Bar()` uses to change how it behaves.

Comment: Very thorough answer. Thank you!